# V2ray api with python

Tags: api, proxy, x-ray, xui

I have a problem with v2ray config file and api request

I wand to send a request to x-ui that iinstalled on my vps to create a user and get data usege of users from another server

I found a python module on github but it rise a connectio error

https://github.com/V2ray-UMP/VUMP-gRPC-client

Can any body help me to how set this?

What is wrong in this config file?

Answer (score 1):

its not for x-ui,
x-ui based on xray not v2ray